# sacar el primer registro de un array de objetos

Tags: array, angular

Agradezco muchísimo su ayuda con el siguiente caso, básicamente requiero filtrar en Angular un array de objetos por "id" y que el resultado de este filtro me devuelva solamente el primer registro por cada *"idBook"*.

A continuación dejo un ejemplo básico para hacerme entender de un array en el que se debe aplicar un filtro que me devuelva el primer elemento por cada *"id"*, se puede ver que tanto el `"id": 1` como el `"id": 2` tienen el mismo `"idBook"` que es 1, solamente requeriría que me devuelva el primer registro, en este caso todo el array de `"id": 1` y todo el array del `"id": 3` ya que tiene un idBook distinto. Muchas gracias y quedo atento.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "idBook": 1,
        "firstName": "First Name 1",
        "lastName": "Last Name 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "idBook": 1,
        "firstName": "First Name 2",
        "lastName": "Last Name 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "idBook": 2,
        "firstName": "First Name 3",
        "lastName": "Last Name 3"
    }
]
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente qué es lo que quieres que devuelva el filtro.

Comment: Vale, ya entendí. Quieres el primer elemento por cada idBook. Enseguida mando mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, el array que pones de ejemplo no es un array bidimensional, es un array de objetos, nota la diferencia entre un array( [1,2] ) y un objeto ( {id:1, name:"Example } ). Asumo que lo que quieres filtrar es ese array de ejemplo.

Siendo el array que quieres filtrar `data`, sería asi:

```js
let data = [ { "id": 1, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 1", "lastName": "Last Name 1" }, { "id": 2, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 2", "lastName": "Last Name 2" }, { "id": 3, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 3", "lastName": "Last Name 3" } ]

let result = data.find( (item) => (item.idBook == 1 ) )

console.log(result)
```

El método find() te permite encontrar el primer elemento que satisfaga la condición que especifíques, en este caso que  `idBook == 1`.

Comment: Por ese lado es la respuesta, sin embargo no sirve que esté estrictamente la condición idBook == 1 ya que voy a iterar esta función sobre muchos objetos, y puede pasar que por ejemplo el id 4 y 5 también coincidan con el mismo idBook, en ese caso requeriría que me devuelva el array de id: 1 y id; 4, ahí como podría hacer? mil gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Sebas1032 El resultado del método find() es solamente un elemento. Si lo que quieres es obtener TODOS los elementos que cumplan esa condición, utiliza el método filter(). Aquí puedes consultar la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Si yo ya estoy utilizando el metodo filter() para que me devuelva los elementos en los cuales coincide el id de una primera tabla con el id de una segunda tabla, pero me devuelve mas de 1 elemento ya que varios idBook coinciden, supongo que a ese metodo filter() tendria que agregarle una nueva funcion para que me retorne solo el primer elemento, supongo que debe ser mandandole el Index de alguna manera para que me tome la posicion 0 pero como te decia no se que falta, te relaciono la parte de mi codigo con el problema. quedo atento.

Comment: arrayAuthorfiltrado = this.authorslista.filter(item => item.idBook = item.id).findIndex[0];

Comment: @Sebas1032 no entiendo bien lo que quieres. Por el codigo anterior, creo que quieres obtener el primer elemento que cumpla: item.idBook == item.id. Si es así tendrias que utilizar .find(item => item.idBook == item.id) en vez de filter(...),findIndex[0]

Answer (score 0):

Muestras un array de objetos .

Para obtener un array seleccionando a los primeros objetos que no tengan el mismo valor de la clave "idBook"

Podemos usar includes().Este nos dice si un determinado elemento existe
, retornara true o false según corresponda
En el código como unicoIdBook inicialmente es un array vacio includes(element.idBook)retornara false y el if lo agregara a unicoIdBook para así continuar agregando o no objetos al nuevo array según corresponda hay otros métodos para también obtener los objetos que no repitan idBook pero te eliminan al primer repetido según tu pregunta quieres conservar al primero repetido y al resto que no repite idBook

```js
let data = [ { "id": 1, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 1", "lastName": "Last Name 1" }, 
{ "id": 2, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 2", "lastName": "Last Name 2" },
 { "id": 3, "idBook": 2, "firstName": "First Name 3", "lastName": "Last Name 3" },
 { "id": 4, "idBook": 2, "firstName": "First Name 4", "lastName": "Last Name 4" },
 { "id": 5, "idBook": 3, "firstName": "First Name 5", "lastName": "Last Name 5" }
 ]

const unicoIdBook = [];
const sinRepetir = data.filter(element => {
  const estaDuplicado = unicoIdBook.includes(element.idBook);
  console.log('unicoIdBook:',unicoIdBook,estaDuplicado)

  if (!estaDuplicado) {
  // el primero en tu caso es false lo agrega al array 
    unicoIdBook.push(element.idBook);

    return true;
  }

  return false;
});
console.log('con idBook no repetido',sinRepetir);
```

Agregue algunos objetos así muestra que retorna solo a los primeros objetos repetidos y al resto sin repetir por "idBook"

```js
/*
con idBook no repetido [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "idBook": 1,
    "firstName": "First Name 1",
    "lastName": "Last Name 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "idBook": 2,
    "firstName": "First Name 3",
    "lastName": "Last Name 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "idBook": 3,
    "firstName": "First Name 5",
    "lastName": "Last Name 5"
  }
]
*/
```

Por Favor edita tu pregunta es un array de objetos no es un array bidimensional

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [{"id": 1, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 1", "lastName": "Last Name 1" }, { "id": 2, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 2", "lastName": "Last Name 2" }, { "id": 3, "idBook": 2, "firstName": "First Name 3", "lastName": "Last Name 3" } ];
```

obtenemos el resultado

```
 let obtener = array.find( (item) => (item.idBook == 1 ));
```

consultamos el resultados

```
console.log(obtener.idBook); // 1
```

Es muy apropiado que valides por si el array llega vacio

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = JSON.parse('[ { "id": 1, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 1", "lastName": "Last Name 1" }, { "id": 2, "idBook": 1, "firstName": "First Name 2", "lastName": "Last Name 2" }, { "id": 3, "idBook": 2, "firstName": "First Name 3", "lastName": "Last Name 3" } ]')

const ids = []
const res = []

//Recorremos el arreglo...
data.forEach(item => {
    //Si aun no "vimos" esa idBook...
    if (!ids.includes(item.idBook)){
        //Agregamos el elemento al resultado y la idBook a la lista de ids
        res.push(item)
        ids.push(item.idBook)
    }
})

console.log(res)
```